# How to find and replace all variables of specified class to same name in IDEA

Tags: java, replace, intellij-idea

Suppose I have a class:

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    public void setName(String name) {};
    public String getName() {}
}
```

In the code of project, there are many different variable names used by the instances of the class `User`:

```
User user = new User();
user.setName(...);

User u = new User();
u.getName();

User member = new User();
member.setName(...)
```

Is there any way to replace all of them into `user` in one operation?

I tried the function "Structure replace" provided by IDEA, but can't do it.

Comment: refract it or do find and replace.

Comment: No, AFIK, you have to find and replace yourself.

Comment: find-usages on constructor, and fix every occurrence manually might og fairly quickly...

Comment: I don't think that you can do this, as it would require a full rename refactoring on each instance name, which is a chore and will soon lead to confusion. However, you probably don't really want to do this anyway. Your example shows that you're using role names for some instance variables, this is a good practice, which you're going to break with your refactor. Although, replacing single letter variables is often a good idea.

Answer (score -2):

Try Edit - Find - Replace, then tick "Regex", type "User [a-z]*". This should get all lines with "User ". Then in replace field type "User "+your identifier and do "Replace all".

Comment: Then you'll end up with
    User user = new User();
    user.setName(...);

    User user = new User();
    u.getName();

    User user = new User();
    member.setName(...)

and a lot of errors.